# How i can create user alerts in Django?

Tags: django, notifications

Subj

Several limitations:

- Warnings should be specific to each user.
- Alerts can also contain links and HTML form (the simplest form
     with empty action ="").
- Table of Contents Alerts should be dynamic, since it must be
     current at all times.
- Types of alerts can be extensible.

It remains only to consider how to store it in a database, and generate and transmit to the template.

```
Examples of alerts:

User <a href="/accounts/64/profile/"> Vlad </ a> commented on your
forum <a href="/forum/topic/54/"> Topic </ a>.

User <a href="/accounts/64/profile/"> Vlad </ a> added to your account to your favorites.

User <a href="/accounts/64/profile/"> Vlad </ a> asks if you add to your favorites.
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="Ok">
<input type="submit" value="No">
</ form>
```

Anybody can explain how to store it in a database, and generate and transmit to the template?

Sorry for my Engl

Answer (score 1):

You could use, or build on, the [Django Messages Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to create one more table, where you will keep data about the user who will recieve alert, user who will send alert and template name, where you will keep alert (so you will need to include it in your main template). Also, you will need one or more boolean fields for flagging this alerts.

So, every time user log in or change page you will check this table and show alerts. If there any, you'll display alert block and put flag into False. So, I think you will need more flags, because one flag will check views of this alert, other will check user answer (like last one form) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use django-alerts library for Send alerts, notifications, and messages based on events (signals) in your django application

installation of alerts

```
pip install django-alert
```

for more information about alert you can try this link [DJANGO-ALERTS](http://djangoalert.com/)

for storing it into the database you can create seperate table/collection and there you can generate schema like user recived , user logged in etc.